# Could M-Theory explain dark matter as well as dark energy?

Tags: string-theory, dark-matter, dark-energy

Is it possible that M-Theory provides a solution to the mystery of dark matter and dark energy?

The idea of dark matter and dark energy is that there is some inexplicable source affecting our universe.

M-Theory suggests that there are other universes as well as our own.  If there were some degree of interaction between the universes, this could explain both the unaccounted for acceleration of our universe's expansion in which dark energy is suggested as well as the unidentified mass of our universe which is termed dark matter.

If the other universes are orthogonal to some or all of our universe's dimensions, then both effects seem very possible.  Could the other universes' mass have some affect within our universe causing the gravitational effects on visible matter, radiation, and the large-scale structure of the universe? Could those universes also be causing the accelerated expansion of our universe by literally pulling it apart through similar gravitational effects.

All of the effects and oddities seem like they would fall out of M-Theory easily.  The extra dimensions of M-Theory seem well-suited for explaining both effects.  Some dimensions could be effected by some alternate universes causing anomalies such as have been detected and relegated to dark matter.  While, maybe, all of the alternate universes could act as a gravitational pull on the very fabric of the universe through the more pedestrian three dimensions, as is suggested for dark energy.

Comment: You know that dark matter and dark energy are *completely* unrelated, right?

Comment: @HDE 226868 Actually, *you* don't know that. They may be related, they may not be.

Comment: @MitchellPorter Okay, yes, you're right. But Mike seemed to be lumping them together as one entity; I was making sure he knows that there isn't necessarily a connection, which is what I see in a lot of cases. I could have phrased my comment better.

Comment: Dark Matter tends to collect around galaxies, or, perhaps more accurately, galaxies collect around it (it seems to collect around itself through gravity).   It might be possible that other universes create diffuse gravity as an explanation of extra gravity, but only around galaxies in our universe.   Also, one is attractive (dark matter) the other repulsive (dark energy).   It strikes me as unlikely to tie opposite forces both to an alternate universe theory.   Can't say definitively either way, but it seems to me, at least, to my small brain, an improbable explanation.

Comment: @userLTK Saying that dark energy is repuslive is just a matter of how you are looking at it.  If it were within our universe then, yes, it would have to be repulsive.  But, if it were other universes on the 3-dimensional boundaries of our universe, then it would be attractive.  In other words, looking at a balloon for instance, something within it would be repulsive to cause expansion, whereas something outside of it would be attractive in that it is pulling from outside.

Comment: Again, I am thinking that, according to most String Theories, there are on the order of eleven dimensions. So, is it possible that some of those dimensions, other than the four easily perceivable dimensions (the others are often described as tightly wound in a small area) work on a scale that would look like what we call dark matter? While the universes act as dark energy on the three (excluding time) easily percieved dimensions. Yes, dark matter and dark energy are unrelated except that they both have no rationalexplanation, so far. They are just something that we don't understand at all.

Comment: @userltk On the subject of dark matter clustering around galaxies, that is part of what makes M_Theory make possible sense to me. There is no telling, as yet, as to how all of those universes impinge on ours (if at all), they could very well, in the extra, non-standard dimensions, affect our universe in a very unconventional way. Those extra dimensions do not seem to span across our universe but wind tightly in a very specific location. Maybe there is an abundance of matter in a particular place in those other universes in specific places that coincide with where our galaxies cluster?

Comment: @curiousone That is true of all String Theories and one of its main difficulties.  They just fits the facts better than most.  Somehow, it seems fitting that the first thing that it could explain had to do with our universe's interaction with others.

Comment: @MikeFowler: Can you point me to a single successful fit of String theory to experimental data? I have not seen any, at least not in a sense that an experimentalist calls "a fit". Don't get me wrong, these models are important, but they have not reached any level of maturity that I would call actual physics. More importantly, I think they all start from the wrong assumption, that gravity is a quantized force. There is, as far as I know, not a shred of evidence for that, but nature seems to be screaming "No! What are you doing!" against that very assumption.

Comment: @curiousone  Err, I think we are in violent agreement...there is no experimental data.  I thought I said that.  There isn't one shred of evidence that gravity exists (and surely not gravitons), except that pull on everything. It seems to me that the space-time warp, alone, does a pretty good job of defining gravity. It would just be one of the greatest pranks of all time if there just wasn't any foothold for a theory of everything.  And, actually, I guess I don't really care about M-Theory except it's universes work better for my ponderings on dark matter/energy than quantum-caused universes.

Comment: @MikeFolwer: There is plenty of evidence that liquids exist and there is ZERO quantum theory for them to be had with exception of a few examples of superfluids. That's the powerful hold that thermodynamics has on quantum mechanics. I think quantum gravitationists could learn something from that example. Is there a theory of everything? Doubtful, but for very mundane reasons (like the actual definition of science) that have absolutely nothing to do with gravity.

Comment: So, to get back on subject, the concept of dark matter and dark energy being alternate universes impinging on our own universe seems like a very viable option.  "Dark", in both cases, could be replaced with "invisible" or, really, "non-existent (in our universe)" for all of the direct evidence, other than the effects.  In fact, in a lot of ways, it is like String Theory in that.

Answer (score 7):

I want to start by clarifying what M-theory is, in relation to string theory, just so the context of my answer will be understood. These days, "string theory" encompasses five ten-dimensional superstring theories, the 11-dimensional M-theory of membranes, 26-dimensional bosonic string theory, "supercritical strings" in more than 10 dimensions, and other topics too. But the first six theories are the core of string theory as physics, and they have a lot of interrelations. In certain limits, the strings of one theory become equivalent to the strings of another theory. For a while, it was thought that M-theory would provide a unified description more fundamental than the five superstring theories, but for now, it's just another corner of the web of interrelations.

The next thing to clarify is that to apply string theory as a description of the world, you need to be even more specific than picking one of the six theories. You might choose to work with "heterotic E8xE8 strings", but then you'll still need to choose which ten-dimensional space-time those strings inhabit. Generally that's a matter of choosing a six-dimensional "Calabi-Yau manifold" as the shape of the six spatial dimensions that we don't see. Your model of the world might be E8xE8 string theory on M^4 x CY6, where M^4 is four-dimensional space-time, and CY6 is the specific Calabi-Yau space.

So having clarified a little how string theory is used as a physical theory... String theory models of physics, including those from its M-theory corner, are definitely meant to include dark matter and dark energy. But it doesn't usually work the way you suggest. In the vast majority of such models, dark matter is just another type of matter in *this* universe, and dark energy is vacuum energy, from quantum fluctuations in empty space.

The closest I can come to your prescription is as follows. There is a branch of M-theory called heterotic M-theory, in which the 11-dimensional space-time is bounded by two 10-dimensional spaces. It's like a sandwich, the two 10-dimensional spaces are the slices of bread, and the eleventh dimension is the thickness of the sandwich. These two spaces on the boundary are like two literally parallel universes, each with its own internal matter and forces. But they can interact gravitationally, because gravity can cross the eleventh dimension.

So in principle, one could have a model where the stars and galaxies of the visible universe exist in one of those boundary spaces, and the "dark matter" is matter in the other space, which because of shared gravity, has gathered around the places over there, corresponding to the galaxies over here. Accounting for dark *energy* as a gravitational interaction between the two spaces is harder, but it does seem to be a standard hope in the ekpyrotic model of bouncing universes, that the accelerated expansion which is attributed to dark energy, can be obtained in such a way.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the insights.  I was thinking that universes were clustered around each other, not really layered.  Vacuum energy as dark energy is interesting.  It's the dark matter existing in this universe that seems awkward or grasping at straws.

Answer (score -1):

Why couldn't gravity taking the extra-dimensional path contribute to the apparent excess of mass when it re-enters a warped brane account for additional mass?